# Thread and concurrency hickup

Tags: java, multithreading

i'm wondering what the code would look like in order to have a program which creates a loop on start. This loop then creates several, thread objects all on their own threads so their all running at the same time, and they all run the same code. Is there a way to do this? as in for example we make 2 threads, they never stop looping and one is always prinintg "thread 1" and 1 is always printing "thread 2" at the same time. This is what i'm wondering. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Is there a way to do this?" Sure. Try it yourself!

Comment: Just to clarify, we don't write code for you here on StackOverflow. You write the code (do at least a basic outline, a `main` method, as much as you possibly can), then post questions about that code if it's not working.

Comment: Don't you have a textbook & tutorials, to guide you for this homework?

Comment: This is not homework, it's a personal project to learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyTask implements Runnable {

    public static id = 0;

    public MyTask(){
        id++;    
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            System.out.print("Thread " + id);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Generator{
    Public static void main(String[] args){
        Runnable[] myTasks = new Runnable[2];
        myTasks[0] = new MyTask(); 
        myTasks[1] = new MyTask(); 

        for(Runnable r: myTasks){
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't compile it. but this is how you are going to do.
When you run class Generator, two Threads will start, and they will print Thread 1. and thread 2 once every one second forever.